# Physical constants seems broken in 10.3

Tags: units

For example, if I just enter `Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]`, then the result is this

```
QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity["GravitationalConstant"]
```

The same goes for Wolfram Alpha inline output, no way to retrieve any quantity.

```
QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[
 QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[None, "PlanckConstant"]]

QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[
 QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[None, "SpeedOfLight"]]
```

Is it just me, or someone else has this problem?

I'm using 10.3.1.0 on Mac OS X

Comment: Seems broken to me (Windows - same version). Tried Round[Quantity[3.5, "Feet"]].

Comment: It's o.k. here, 10.3.1 on Windows 10

Comment: @swish: I should have mentioned, I am using 10.3.1, Windows, 64-bit and I am having the same issue from your first example and the example I gave above.

Comment: Works for me (10.3.1.0, Mac OS X v10.11.2)

Comment: Also works fine on my Mac (10.3.1.0, Mac OS X v10.11.2).

Comment: Works for me (10.3.1; Windows 8.1). @Variable 's example also works. Perhaps your internet connection is down?

Comment: @swish I removed the version and OS tags because of [this meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/should-we-ask-for-tag-warnings)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Thanks for that update, my internet is working. There seem to be some serious intermittent bug with the interface to the internet also. As much as I hate to say it, new releases have gotten much more buggy over the years.